# IBOutlet image view redraws itself when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, iboutlet

I can't figure out what is happening with my custom UITableViewCell.

The header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *personName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *detailedTextLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *amountLabel;

@end
```

The implementation file:

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {}
    return self;
}
```

There is also a XIB file. The layout is an image view on the left and text and detailed text on the right.

Here is the problem. These custom cells are used in a UITableViewController. When I select one of the UITableViewCell, the imageView would shift to the right instead of being in the center when it initially gets loaded.

The most confusing thing is that the problem goes away if I add @synthesize to the implementation. As far as I know, the synthesize adds setter and getters however, in my implementation file, those properties are not set anywhere. They are an IBOutlet property so that my XIB can connect to them. Please tell me what might be going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no needs to synthesize the outlets. Seems like there are autolayouts enabled on xib file. Just disable them and try again.

Comment: I did and it does not work. In fact, I went through every commit, git checkout to find this defect but can't understand it.

Comment: built on 7 but made to run on ios 6